# Rubymotion App in different ios

Tags: ios, ruby, ios7, rubymotion

Have an rubymotion IOS app in Appstore but when device with lower version than ios 7, the app can't be installed and said it require at least ios 7. Is the problem is come from rubymotion configuration or any where else?

Someone can point me out?

Thanks...

Here is the solution:

app.deployment_target = '6.1'

This will make you ios app available on ios 6.1 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your APP's `Deployment Target` maybe is 7.0. then it's not available in lower version.

You can check your Deployment Target in `General` tab of the target setting in your project.

Comment: Oic...so it meant this is configured in Apple Store ?

Comment: in your project settings

Comment: hmm,I'm using rubymotion. So basically I have to set my app.deployment_target = '6.1' ? or app.deployment_target >= '6.1' ? is  greater or equal is acceptable?

Comment: yes. maybe you need to test on 6.1 and later. then resubmit to app store.

Comment: kay, so final confirmation be4 i accept the ans: I can use app.deployment_target = '6.1', it meant the minimum will be 6.1 and higher...

Comment: yep. it's available in ios 6.1 and later.